# Como actualizar datos en Firebase desde android studio?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, update

tengo un problema para actualizar mi database de firebase desde Android. Tengo una clase llamada Pedidos donde almaceno los diferentes pedidos que guardo en la database, desde el Activity listado_pedidos muestro en un listview los diferentes pedidos, desde aqui tambien envío un bundle con los datos a actualizar cuando se presiona el boton "actualizar". Desde otro activity llamado actualizar_pedido, recibo el bundle con el objeto pero al momento de actualizar no se que hago mal que no funciona.

Les dejo el codigo de ambos activitys.

Listado_pedidos:

```
private ListView lista;
private ArrayList<Pedidos> listaPedidos = new ArrayList<>();
//private Button btnAc;

Pedidos pedidosSelected;

//Declaramos datos para obtener la instancia de la database
FirebaseDatabase firebase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado_pedidos);

    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    //btnAc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAc);

    inicializarBase(); //Iniciar mi database

    //Metodo para obtener la seleccion del listview
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {

            pedidosSelected = (Pedidos) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            
        }
    });

    databaseReference.child("Pedidos").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for( DataSnapshot op : snapshot.getChildren()) //Recorremos la entidad
            {
                Pedidos p = op.getValue(Pedidos.class); //Guardamos la consulta en el objeto
                listaPedidos.add(p); //Añadimos el objeto al arreglo
                ArrayAdapter adapt = new ArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaPedidos);
                lista.setAdapter(adapt);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}

//Metodo para eliminar pedido
public void eliminarPedido(View view)
{
    Pedidos p = new Pedidos();
    p.setId(pedidosSelected.getId());

    databaseReference.child("Pedidos").child(p.getId()).removeValue();
    listaPedidos.clear();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Has eliminado un pedido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}



public void inicializarBase()
{
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();//Obtengo la instancia
    databaseReference = firebase.getReference();//Obtengo la referencia

}

public void actualizarpedido(View view)
{
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {

            Pedidos pedidoActualizar = listaPedidos.get(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(listado_pedidos_activity.this, actualizar_pedidos.class);

            Bundle bun = new Bundle();
            bun.putSerializable("pedido",pedidoActualizar);

            i.putExtras(bun);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}
```

}

Y este es el activity donde quiero actualizar al database:

```
private EditText name, fec, det, com, idd;
private Button btn;
//String idPedido;

//Declaramos datos para obtener la instancia de la database
FirebaseDatabase firebase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actualizar_pedidos);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    fec = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fecha);
    det = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.deta);
    com = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.come);
    idd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idd);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAc);


    inicializarBase(); //Iniciar mi database

    Bundle objetoEnviado = getIntent().getExtras();
    Pedidos pe=null;


    if(objetoEnviado!=null)
    {
        pe = (Pedidos) objetoEnviado.getSerializable("pedido");

        idd.setText(pe.getId().toString().trim());
        name.setText(pe.getNombre().toString().trim());
        fec.setText(pe.getFecha().toString().trim());
        det.setText(pe.getDetalles().toString().trim());
        com.setText(pe.getComentarios().toString().trim());
    }

}


public void inicializarBase()
{
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();//Obtengo la instancia
    databaseReference = firebase.getReference();//Obtengo la referencia

}

public void actPedido(View view)
{
    //Actualizamos la database
    Pedidos p = new Pedidos();


    Map<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("nombre", name.getText().toString());
    hashMap.put("fecha", fec.getText().toString());
    hashMap.put("comentarios", com.getText().toString());
    hashMap.put("detalles", det.getText().toString());


    databaseReference.child("Pedidos").updateChildren(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object o) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Actualizado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });      

}
```

}

Comment: Revisaste el LogCat que indica?